# How does a mute person pray salah?

Tags: salat, reciting

I'm in contact with a revert brother who was born deaf. He can't speak either. He is currently learning to recite Arabic for salah, and he says he's just thinking about the meaning and moving his lips. Is this the way someone who can't speak / hear his own recitation should offer salah? Or is there a better way I could recommend to him?